# Groovy Rest Api

Tags: rest, grails, groovy

I'm using groovy to make REST API, I am providing Real Shop integration Rest Api. But I get the soapui and the code connection reset error.So can you guys help me with this problem?

**Real is getSignature method:**

```
private String getSignature(Map params) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {

    String plainText = "GET" + "\n" + params.endpointUrl + "\n" + "" + "\n" + timess
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256")
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(params.password.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256")
    mac.init(secretKeySpec)
    byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(plainText.getBytes())
    return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(rawHmac)
}
```

https://www.real.de/api/v1/?page=rest-api

**My Code:**

```
@Override
protected Map getCategories(Map params) {
    params.authentication.timestamp = (System.currentTimeMillis() /1000L)

    String signature = getSignature(params.authentication)
    def client = new RESTClient( params.authentication.endpointUrl )
    Map response = client.get( path : 'categories',
    headers: [
        'accept': application/json,
        'hm-client' : params.authentication.apiKey,
        'hm-signature' : signature,
        'hm-timestamp' : params.authentication.timestamp,
        //'sslTrustAllCerts': true
    ]
    )

    assert response.status == 200 // HTTP response code
    println response.getData()
    return response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see in the documentation which you shared(https://www.real.de/api/v1/?page=rest-api) if your client and server times can be different from each other about 5 minutes. If the time get over 5 minutes then connection will rejected. Could you check the server time and client time ?

- Paragraph
  "HM-Timestamp - All requests must contain an HM-Timestamp header with the current Unix Timestamp in seconds and must be current at the time the request is made. There is a 10-minute window around the current time to account for clock skew. In other words, your timestamp can be up to 5 minutes earlier or 5 minutes later than the current server time. If the timestamp is more than 5 minutes different from the current server time when the request is received, the request will be rejected."

Comment: Thank you for your answer.We send in time of request. I do not think it's about it.  Do you have any other idea.